# Append an element to each atomic vector in a list in R

Tags: r, list, append

I would like to add elements to atomic vectors in a list. For example, from the list:

```
my_list <- list(c("apple", "pear"), c("carrot", "turnip"))
```

I would like to add elements `elements = c("banana","aubergine")` such that each element is appended in sequence to the end of the vector:

```
ny_new_list <- list(c("apple", "pear", "banana"), c("carrot","turnip", "aubergine"))
```

I have thought of using `unlist` and then adding each element in the vector `elements` in position 3,6,9 etc., but this seems unwieldy and you have to manually change the code depending on how long the vectors in `my_list` are.

Comment: I recommend turning that list into a data.frame. Then you could just use `rbind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Map` + `append`:

```r
Map(append, my_list, elements)

# [[1]]
# [1] "apple"  "pear"   "banana"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "carrot"    "turnip"    "aubergine"
```

Comment: `Map(c, my_list, elements)` slightly compact